# Testing issue with LUIS bot on Bot framework emulator

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, ngrok

I am following this guide to develop chatbot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#test-the-bot

When I tried to test the bot with Bot Framework Emulator, I am unable to get a response.

```
[15:17:43]Emulator listening on http://[::]:60595
[15:17:43]ngrok not configured (only needed when connecting to remotely hosted bots)
[15:17:43]Connecting to bots hosted remotely
[15:17:43]Edit ngrok settings
[15:17:43]-> conversationUpdate
[15:17:44]POST500directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities
[15:17:51]-> messagehi
[15:17:51]POST500directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities
```

Is this have to do with my company security blocking ngrok?
My Echo bot works fine, but seems like I am having issue with the LUIS function. Is there a way to make it work and link it to MS teams?

Help needed

Comment: Can you provide some additional information on what issue you are getting? You should not need ngrok to test a bot locally. You only need this if services outside of your bot need to reach the bot on the internet instead of on your PC. That's what ngrok does, it exposes your locally running bot to the internet. I test all the time with LUIS, QnA Maker, Azure Storage, etc. without using ngrok.

Comment: One other thing I'll add, if you have a proxy you will need to make some changes in your local `.env` file to get through that. And when you're running locally, you do NOT need to (and should not) provide your MS appid and password, since you are only running on emulator. I initially had an issue with that, and removing those values allowed the bot to run.

Comment: As @billoverton stated, if you have a proxy, then you will have to configure the changes in your code. Refer to https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3055#issuecomment-312236113

Comment: hi @billoverton i'm using python code, are you able to help me pinpoint where exactly to change? 
I have added below 2 line to app.py, but seems like its not working

set http_proxy=http://proxy-web.company.com:XX
set https_proxy=http://proxy-web.company.com:XX

Comment: hi @ranusharao i'm using python code, are you able to help me pinpoint where exactly to change? I have added below 2 line to app.py, but seems like its not working                 
               set http_proxy=proxy-web.company.com:XX                                                 
               set https_proxy=proxy-web.company.com:XX